# Does exist an only spring mvc archetype?

Tags: spring, maven-2, spring-mvc

Im searching a spring mvc archetype with no hibernate implementations because i found an appfuse archetype but it comes with hibernate...

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of any archetypes containing only Spring MVC but you can

- Use [SpringSource Tools Suite](http://www.springsource.com/developer/sts)'s Spring MVC template project (imho you should use STS anyway for Spring development) OR
- Use [Spring Roo](http://www.springsource.org/roo) to generate a skeleton for you; create a dummy entity then create controller for it OR
- Build it yourself based on any of the resources available, e.g. [this screencast](http://blog.springsource.com/2010/07/22/spring-mvc-3-showcase/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

[Please see more usages here](http://blog.springsource.com/2009/12/02/obtaining-spring-3-artifacts-with-maven/)